# Conditional probabilities: Overdetermined system (conditioning a probability with redundant/extra information)

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

**Question:** Does $p(A|B,C)=p(A|B)$ if we presume that $A=B$ (or $A=f(B)$ more generally)?

**Background:**

I've been wrestling with overdetermined systems for some time.

Presume the following relation

$$A = B\,,$$

or alternatively ($A = f(B)$), then I know that the probability of $A$ conditioned on $B$

$$p(A|B)=\delta (A-B)\,,$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the delta functions and $p$ stands for probability (density).

Can I claim that

$$p(A|B,C) = \delta (A-B)\,,$$

without knowing the properties of $C$?

**Attempt at a solution**

If I expand the system using Bayes' theorem, seemingly the answer is **no**:

$$p(A|B,C) = \frac{p(C|A,B)}{p(C|B)} p(A|B) \neq p(A|B) \text{, unless p(C|A,B)=p(C|B)}\,.$$

However, the reason I'm struggling is the following:

Intuitively, if $B$ determines $A$, and we know $B$, then by definition we should know $A$ with certainty. If we know A with certainty, then regardless of any other information, the probability that $A=f(B)$ should be unity.

This would allow us to write, for example,
$$p(A|C) = \int p(A|B)p(B|C) \mathrm{d}B,$$
which is a very nice and useful relation, if correct.

**Question:**

Is $p(A|B,C)=p(A|B)$ if we know that $A=B$ (or $A=f(B)$ more generally)? Why/why not?

Or is this simply ill-determined somehow?

Comment: If what sense are you using $A = B$ (or $A = f(B)$)? If they are exactly equal or almost surely equal then $p(C|A,B) = p(C|B,B) = p(C|B)$, so there is no contradiction from Bayes.

Comment: DavidLukeThiessen Hmm, and I suppose that, if $A=f(B)$, then $p(C|A,B)=p(C|A=f(B),B)=p(C|B)$? 

I may have been overthinking things.